# Did the 1937 single issue magazine "Rising Tide" include the "Rules for Revolution"?

Tags: united-states, germany, propaganda

The New York Times 10 July 1970 article  [Communist ‘Rules’ For Revolt Viewed As Durable Fraud](https://www.nytimes.com/1970/07/10/archives/communist-rules-for-revolt-viewed-as-durable-fraud-rules-for.html) inaccurately states:

> The earliest publication of the “rules” turned up in search was in The New World News of February, 1946. Many who reproduce the “rules” quote the defunct biweekly newsletter of **Moral Re‐Armament** Inc. as their source.

> Morris Kominsky, in a book called “The Hoaxers,” to be published soon by Branden Press of Boston, quotes H. Mead Twitchell Jr., until recently an employee of the now closed Los Angeles office of **Moral Re‐Armament**, as saying that the “rules” appeared in German “in a German paper during the twenties and thirties, was translated into English in Britain [and] I believe it was first used in the United States in Rising Tide, a magazine published about 1937, but I can not find a copy to check this and do not know the name of the German newspaper.”

> **The only magazine called Rising Tide that circulated in the United States, according to a check by librarians, was a periodical for boys and girls of the Presbyterian Church of England, published from 1880 to 1937**.
> (emphasis added)

However, in 1937 there was a [single issue magazine "Rising Tide"](https://www.ebay.com/itm/275653838737) published by the [Oxford Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Group), affiliated with the [Moral Re-armament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_Re-Armament) movement mentioned by in the above NYT quote.

Was H. Mead Twitchell Jr. accurate in stating that the 1937 "Rising Tide" magazine included the ["Rules for Revolution"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_World_News/-1p8Vf3WfooC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22rules%20for%20revolution%22) which were published in the February 1946 New World News?

Comment: Please add a bit of context for those of us unfamiliar with what these rules are/represent. Thanks.

Comment: @Oddthinking the rules are highly related to this question: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31405/were-these-communist-rules-for-revolution-written-in-1919 , but the 1946 and 1947 publications of the rules didn't say they were "communist".

Comment: I don't quite see why this counts as a *notable* claim.

Comment: @quarague because it was published in the New York Times, the book "The Hoaxers: Plain Liars, Fancy Liars and Damned Liars" and the journal "The Dixon Line"

Comment: Rising Tide (1937) does not look so glum as to contain these Rules, but maybe they get darker on the unphotographed pages:  https://recoverycollectibles.com/products/rising-tide-oxford-group-1938 ----
Here is an attempt of reaffirming the authenticity of the Rules by having them seized in 1919, then given to MRA in 1946 : still sounds fishy, American Zone Koblenz is way off from Düsseldorf, and why would the Americans raid in a French/British zone?
https://www.jstor.org/stable/community.28146662?seq=2 ----- Can someone link to the '46 New World News? I can't even find that one